# Remove custom analyzer / filter on Elasticsearch for all new indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

We tried adding a customer analyzer / lowercase filter to all new indexes in Elasticsearch. It looks something like this:

```
       "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": []
        }
      }
    },
```

This is automatically applied to all new indexes. How do I remove this? I realize i can not remove this from existing indexes, but how do i stop it from being automatically added to new ones?

It appears that these settings are located somewhere in my master "template". I can see the template using "GET /_template", which contains all of the unwanted lowercase normalizers... but how do i remove them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can delete and index template

DELETE /_template/template_1

Also in future if you want to add a new custom analyzer to any template first make a testing index with your custom analyzer and then test if you custom analyzers is giving you desired results by following

```
GET <index_name>/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "analyzer_name",
  "text" : "this is a test"
}
```